# Examples of Metric space with and without a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

Question: Give an example of two metric spaces $(E, d_1)$,$(E, d_2)$  and of a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty \in E$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists in $(E, d_1)$ but does not exist in $(E, d_2)$.

Would the discrete metric space, Euclidean metric space, or regular one count as either, or what are some examples that are. Or what is the question really asking. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Let $d_1$ be the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ and $d_2$ be the discrete metric. Then $\frac 1 n \to 0$ in $d_1$ but not in $d_2$. In fact $d_2(x_n,x)\to 0$ is possible only when $x_n=x$ for all sufficiently large values of $n$.